# How to use many to one associations in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, annotations, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I'm using Doctrine 2 in Zend.

I'm trying to figure out how to access the properties/method for related models from the current object.

For example, we have two tables: Schools and Students.

Many Students belong to a school, so this is a **many to one** relationship and I'm only interested in listing all the students for each school. I do not wish to query student records to find the details of the school they belong to therefore this is classed as a **unidirectional** relationship.

Now to set up the **many to one** relationship in Doctrine 2 between the tables I'd add this in the Students entity, as it is the **owning side**:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Schools")
 * @JoinColumn(name="school_id", referencedColumnName="school_id")
 */
private $schoolId;
```

Where the name values correspond the column names in the students table and schools table respectively.

So if I have an object of a Schools record, how do I access the student properties/methods?

```
echo $oSchool->Students->getName(); // doesn't work
```

I can't understand what I have done wrong, the proxy class is being generated. Appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Schools entity you'd want to have something like this

```
/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $property
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Students", mappedBy="school")
 */
private $student;

public function __construct() {
    $this->student = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function getStudent() {
    return $this->student;
}
```

With this you could do something like the following, which gives you an [ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.0/doctrine/common/collections/arraycollection.html) with all student objects

```
$studentsArray = $school->getStudent();
```

Hope that helps... Docrine 2 is very powerful but some things are not documented very well. Some more information on this in the Documentation at [Working with Assiciations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-associations.html).

Comment: Would this work even if I don't have a student_id in the schools table?

Comment: In this setting you would not have a student_id in the school table but rather have a school_id in the student table. This way you can relate many students to one school.

Comment: I tried the approach you outlined and got the following errors:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampplite\htdocs\test\library\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1205

Fatal error: Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object in C:\xampplite\htdocs\test\library\Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection.php on line 168

Comment: Maybe you want to post both classes you wrote. With these bits of code its nearly impossible to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing this issue:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object in C:\xampplite\htdocs\test\library\Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection.php on line 168 –"

**Solution:** Need to replace mappedBy value with doctrine property value instead of Table column name

Ex:

**Correct Syntax:** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Test\Entity\School", mappedBy="school")

**Wrong Syntax:** Correct syntax: @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Test\Entity\School", mappedBy="school_id")

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress. I read the '[Working with Objects](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html)' section of Doctrine 2's documentation.

Associated objects can be accessed by something like this (according to the example given in my question):

```
$oStudent->getSchoolId()->getName(); // gets a student's school's name by traversing the school class
```

However in my orignal question, I wanted to access the students belonging to a school via the schools object. I am completely stumped on how to do this, It seems to me its not possible.